# If $11+11=4$ and $22+22=16$, then $33+33=\text{???}$ (Facebook math quiz)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle, pattern-recognition

From a Facebook math quiz:

$$\begin{align}
11 + 11 &= 4 \\
22 + 22 &= 16 \\
33 + 33 &= \text{???}
\end{align}$$

Maybe I'm just stupid but the answer to this is $36$, however I think it should be zero.

The reason I think this is because if you do $22 / 4 = 5.5$ then $44 / 16 = 2.75$. If you do $5.5 - 2.75$ it equals $2.75$, so the rate of change is $-2.75$. I think that that means the answer should be $0$.

Am I right or am I wrong?

Comment: ... or you are just halving the ratio at every step (i.e. doubling the RHS). Hard to interpolate linearly a single number without a lot of disagreement.

Comment: Interpreting concatenation and addition as meaning multiplication, I get 81.

Comment: That's interesting I didn't think about halving the ratio that would make sense. So it could be 90.75

Comment: this is not [tag:abstract-algebra]

Comment: Anything is abstract if you are brave enough.

Comment: @RghtHndSd: Interpreting concatenation as addition, and addition as multiplication, gives the "official" answer of $36$. (Of course, with stuff like this, lots of answers can be considered valid.)

Comment: @Blue And exactly because of this , this is no math.

Comment: Another reasonable guess : First line - we add the digits Second line we muliply the digits Thirs line : We exponent the digits to get the huge number $\ 3\uparrow \uparrow 4=3\uparrow 3\uparrow 3\uparrow 3\ $. If no context is given, at least more examples should be given. This still makes the solution not unique, but would give the reader a better chance to guess the intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that both 11+11=4 and 22+22=16 doesn't prove the pattern exists. i.e. 1+1=2, 2+2=4, but 3+3=10 in base 6. Another example would be that the origin of the euclidean plane and (1,1) are common to all basic exponential curves, that two examples fall into infinite patterns where every other point is unique.

Comment: That makes sense thanks for the response.

Comment: both your solution and nn+nn=(2n)^2 are true.